# Polymer - app-storage: Remove entry and update storage

Tags: javascript, polymer, local-storage, polymer-2.x, vaadin-grid

I ran into a problem when trying to update the value of an array inside my .
I've been searching on google since last 4 hours, but no luck
I have the follwing code:

```
<!--
@license
Copyright (c) 2016 The Polymer Project Authors. All rights reserved.
This code may only be used under the BSD style license found at http://polymer.github.io/LICENSE.txt
The complete set of authors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/AUTHORS.txt
The complete set of contributors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/CONTRIBUTORS.txt
Code distributed by Google as part of the polymer project is also
subject to an additional IP rights grant found at http://polymer.github.io/PATENTS.txt
-->

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/vaadin-grid/vaadin-grid.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/vaadin-date-picker/vaadin-date-picker.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-storage/app-localstorage/app-localstorage-document.html">






<dom-module id="my-view1">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
      :host {
        display: block;

        padding: 10px;
      }
      .form {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      .form paper-input {
        flex: 1;
        margin-right: 10px;
      }
      .form vaadin-date-picker {
        flex: 1;
        margin-top: 10px;

      }
      .form paper-button {
        margin-top: 10px;
        align-self: flex-end;
      }

    </style>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="form">
      <paper-input label="Sum" value="{{todo.task}}" auto-validate placeholder="Suma" required=true pattern="[0-9]*" error-message="Numbers only"></paper-input>
      <vaadin-date-picker label="Date" value="{{todo.due}}"></vaadin-date-picker>
      <paper-button raised on-tap="_addToDo">Add</paper-button>
      </div>
<br>
      <vaadin-grid id="grid" items={{todos}}>

        <vaadin-grid-column width="calc(50% - 100px)">
          <template class="header">Sum</template>
          <template>{{item.task}}</template>
      </vaadin-grid-column>

    <vaadin-grid-column width="calc(50% - 100px)">
      <template class="header">Date</template>
      <template>{{item.due}}</template>
    </vaadin-grid-column>

    <vaadin-grid-column>
        <template>
          <div style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end;">
            <paper-button raised on-tap="_remove">remove</paper-button>

          </div>
        </template>
      </vaadin-grid-column>

  </vaadin-grid>
    </div>
<app-localstorage-document key="todos" data="{{todos}}">
</app-localstorage-document>
  </template>



  <script>
    class MyView1 extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'my-view1'; }

      static get properties() {
        return {
          todo: {
            type: Object,
            value: () => { return {} }
          },
          todos: {
            type: Array,
            value: () => []
          }
        };
      }

      _addToDo() {
        this.push('todos', this.todo);
        this.todo = {};
      };

      _remove(e) {
        var index = this.todos.indexOf(e.model.item);
          this.todos.splice(index, 1);
          this.$.grid.clearCache();
      };


    }


    window.customElements.define(MyView1.is, MyView1);

  </script>
</dom-module>
```

I'm trying to update localStorage after removing one of the items. 
I have no idea how to "commit the update". Is there any way to update the localStorage after removing the item? Thanks!

Comment: Can you try `this.splice('todos', index, 1)` instead of `this.todos.splice(index, 1);` and see if it works?

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thanks a lot! How can I select your comment as the answer?

Comment: You can check my answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you manipulate an array using the native methods (like `Array.prototype.splice`), you must notify Polymer after the fact. 
So, you can notify using `notifySplices`. More about [notifySplices](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/elements/Polymer.Element#method-notifySplices).

OR, use the Polymer methods for array mutations.

Every Polymer element has the following array mutation methods available:

```
push(path, item1, [..., itemN]) 
pop(path) 
unshift(path, item1, [...,
itemN])
shift(path)
splice(path, index, removeCount, [item1, ..., itemN])
```

You are not required to notify if you are using Polymer array mutation method.
So, use `this.splice('todos', index, 1)` instead of `this.todos.splice(index, 1);`, this will notify changes made in the array `todos` which will reflect changes in the localstorage as well.